# How to move node position keeping right angles?

Tags: editing, angles, nodes, rectangle

I made a polygon with perpendicular segments using CAD Tools.  I saw that, even if the segments of this polygon are perpendicular, the four points has different values in terms of x, y. I think that`s because of the projection. 
[image]

The thing is that now I want to expand the polygon but keeping the lower-right point and also, right angles. I duplicated it and I tried to keep the right angles but, manually, it`s impossible. How can I do that ?
[image]

Comment: At least you can select two corner points with the node tool by holding Ctrl pressed and drag them both together so that the segment is moving parallel.